# How to change an Excel cell when the value retrived from database is diferent?

Tags: java, excel, vba

The notation of cell is ${detalhes.origim.name()}, return a String in cell but the name of string is always "TEST_TEST" but i need to rename on this spreadsheet to something like "Teste beautiful form". this notation can return just 4 diferent names. Is there any way to use a switch case on excel? ty.

I try module on vba but didnt work, how can i rename this?
Code i try:

```
Dim score As String, result As String
score = Range("F5").Value

Select Case score
   Case "CONTAS_PAGAR"
      result = "Contas a pagar"
   Case "CONTAS_RECEBER"
      result = "Contas a receber"
   Case "MOVIMENTO_BANCARIO"
      result = "Movimento bancário"
   Case "MOVIMENTO_CAIXA"
      result = "Movimento de caixa"
   Case Else
      result = "Não encontrado"
End Select
Range("F6").Value = result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if packaged in a **SUB()**:

```
Sub vini()
    Dim score As String, result As String

    score = Range("F5").Value

    Select Case score
       Case "CONTAS_PAGAR"
          result = "Contas a pagar"
       Case "CONTAS_RECEBER"
          result = "Contas a receber"
       Case "MOVIMENTO_BANCARIO"
          result = "Movimento bancário"
       Case "MOVIMENTO_CAIXA"
          result = "Movimento de caixa"
       Case Else
          result = "Não encontrado"
    End Select
    Range("F6").Value = result
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

As a function:

```
Function vini(score As String) As String
    Select Case score
       Case "CONTAS_PAGAR"
          result = "Contas a pagar"
       Case "CONTAS_RECEBER"
          result = "Contas a receber"
       Case "MOVIMENTO_BANCARIO"
          result = "Movimento bancário"
       Case "MOVIMENTO_CAIXA"
          result = "Movimento de caixa"
       Case Else
          result = "Não encontrado"
    End Select

    vini = result
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Where and how can i put this in cell?

Comment: @ViníciusMartins it's a macro, it's meant to be *executed*, not "put into a cell". Macros aren't *user-defined functions*. If you want to type `=SomeFunction(F5)` in `F6` then make it a `Function` instead of a `Sub`, and parameterize it with a `Range`. Read up on "Excel UDF" for more info.

Comment: @ViníciusMartins  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: It works when i put some text in cell, but in this case is a javaee system. and generate this excel when i click to generate on site. i need to recive ${mestre.origim.name()} need to change dinamic